# Evaluating binary classifiers with emphasis on positive-class

Tags: classification, model-evaluation

I'm evaluating a series of binary classifiers and I care about how one performs better than the other for the same task, albeit under different settings. In my use case, I do not particularly care about the True Negative rate. I have been using binary/positive $F_{1}$-score to "focus" on the positive class in my evaluation, however, I have noticed where this can become a problem for comparison:

Take, for example, two models, $M_{A}$ and $M_{B}$, for comparison, with following ground-truth labels of shape (10,):

$Y = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]$

If $M_{A}$ predicts $[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]$, I achieve an $F_{1}$-score of **0.5714** when $Y=1$

But if I have a model, $M_{B}$, which does not converge at all, and spams out 10 positive predictions, I get a score of **0.6667** (recurring), giving the appearance that $M_{B}$ outperforms $M_{A}$ despite not being able to discern between classes.

How can I emphasise the positive-class in that I don't care about True Negatives and perhaps False Negatives, but I do care about both True and False Positives?

I have looked into using Balanced Accuracy as a metric but I was a little afraid that, while this seems to capture label imbalance, it assumes that both labels are equally important. I have also looked into $F_{\beta}$-score in which I can assign a weight to either class, however, how do I "determine" this seemingly arbitrary weight?

Comment: If you don’t care about catching true negatives, why predict anything as a negative? Skip all of the fancy modeling. Your function is ```def apgsov_classifier(data):
    return(1)```.

Comment: I do care about "catching" them, I don't care about reporting True Negatives when comparing the evaluation output from my models in which I'm primarily concerned with the positive class.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "hard" 0-1 classifications, but probabilistic classifications. Evaluate these using [proper scoring rules](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info). Separate the probabilistic prediction aspect from the *subsequent* decision, where you might indeed use [thresholds](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312119/1352), but only after carefully considering the costs of decisions versus outcomes. The F1 score (and all related KPIs, like accuracy, precision, sensitivity etc.) silently assume a very specific cost and conflate the two aspects. See the links in [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603663/1352).