# Low F1 score in a propensity model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, inference, modeling

I'm trying to model a propensity problem to a product, which is highly unbalanced (99.9% against 0.1%). Here is the details of my dataset:

- The target is a flag which indicates if the client bought the product in the future interval of 20 days;
- If the client buys the product, he receives a flag 1, and 0 otherwise;
- The dataset has 99.9% of 0 and 0.1% of 1 for each day.

  - For example, we have a database of 1k clients in day 1, and just 1 client brought the product;
  - We have a database of 2k clients in day 10, and just 2 clients brought the product;
- To model this problem, I tried two approaches:

  - I've made an undersample on the majority class (0), and after that I create the train and test sets. That approach gives me a very good F1 score (about 0.9). However, when I evaluate the model on future data, I've got a very low F1 score (0.1, high recall and low precision).

    - I think this is because the "real life data" isn't balanced, and my test set used for the F1 calculation wasn't unbalanced.
  - I've made an undersample just on the training set, and evaluate the problem on a test set which didn't had a previous undersample. Now, I've got a realistic F1 score (0.1, high recall and low precision);
- I'm using transactional features on other products and sociodemografic features;
- I tested the Gradient Boost and Random Forest algorithms;
- The model is intended to score the model daily.

My question is: Any of my approaches is correct? And, how can I get a better score?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! One issue to consider is why you want to optimize your $F_1$ score [when proper statistical methods show such a statistic to have considerable issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603663/academic-reference-on-the-drawbacks-of-accuracy-f1-score-sensitivity-and-or-sp).

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm going to read the references.