# ROC with bootstraping

Tags: bootstrap, roc, auc, rms

I have a data with 2 variables: diagnosis- yes/no
Score- numeric variable from 0-10.
I need to do ROC analysis for this data and to find the best cut off values.

The problem is the data is too small so I can't split it to train and test data.

I understand I need to do build a bootstraped data set, build the model and then see how it functions on the original data and repeat this process X times.
From what I have read I can achieve that by **rms:validate** in r.

However, this gives me only the general AUC without the ability to run and plot models with different cut-offs of the score.
Is there another way to achieve my goal?
Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! The Wynants article discussed in [this Cross Validated answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/603667/247274) discusses small sample sizes leading to unstable optimal thresholds. Sure, you might run bootstrap well and get the optimal threshold to be $0.3$, but if the optimal thresholds in your bootstrap interactions has an interquartile range of $0.1$ to $0.5$, how much would you trust that $0.3$ threshold?

Comment: Well it's not that small. I have 167 observations, but the patients with positive diagnosis is only 27. Anyway I have to run the analysis so just searching for the most 'correct' way to do it.