# Is there an equivalent for Yates' correction for a confusion matrix-derived metrics?

Tags: decision-theory, confusion-matrix, sensitivity-specificity, f1

Given the following table of predictions vs. actual states:

```
    A     B     C     D
A  11     9     4     3
B   2   120     3     6
C   1     1     9     3
D   0     0     0     0
```

You can see that none of the actual states are D. I wish to calculate some confusion table metrics (I can handle the multi-level issue), but the 0 cells for D mean that I'll have some undefined outcomes. Is it valid to add 0.5 to every cell in the table then calculate the metrics? If so, does this have a formal name?

Comment: The person's name is *Yates*, so the apostrophe conventionally follows the "s", rather than precedes it.

Comment: So, you have nothing substantive to add.

Comment: Okay, I'll fix your question for you. Since people use the search facility to find answers, names - especially in titles - *matter*. But keep shooting barbs instead of improving your own question if that helps you get through the day.

Answer (score 0):

I find the idea to be problematic, particularly in your situation.

You have some rather small numbers in your table, such as $1$. By adding $0.5$ to every value, you increase the size of that value by a considerable amount: $1$ to $1.5$ represents a $50\%$ increase. This will distort your downstream calculations, perhaps quite dramatically.

Further, if you do the calculation with the zero-cells as $0.5$, you are giving incorrect values. The fact is that you never predicted category $D$. If you start reporting that some percent of the items predicted as category $D$ actually were category $D$, I do not see how such reporting reflects the reality of your results.

Comment: It could also be worth considering if you should be evaluating these metrics that are derived from the confusion matrix, which are [more problematic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603663/247274) than you might think.