# Matthews' Correlation Coefficient and Leave-One-Out Cross Validation

Tags: correlation, cross-validation, confusion-matrix

How do I determine Matthews' Correlation Coefficient for leave-one-out cross-validation? There doesn't seem to be a way to average the coefficient across folds - one element is insufficient support for calculating MCC.

Comment: Look at the [math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient#Machine_learning). Lay out under what situations such a function would be defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $N$ total observations, you’ll fit $N$ models to perform the leave-one-one cross validation (LOOCV). Each of these will produce one predicted category.

After running the LOOCV, you will wind up with an $N$-vector of predictions. To get the Matthews correlation coefficient, calculate the Pearson correlation between this $N$-vector of predictions and the $N$-vector of true values, where you have encoded the predictions and true values as numbers (likely $0$ and $1$ or $\pm 1$).

It might help to look at a code example.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000
x <- rt(N, 1)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
preds <- rep(NA, N)
for (i in 1:N){
    
    xi <- x[-i]
    yi <- y[-i]
    
    L <- glm(yi ~ xi, family = binomial)
    preds[i] <- predict(L, data.frame(
        xi = x[i],
        type = "link"
    ))
}
predicted_categories <- round(preds)
mcc <- cor(y, predicted_categories)
mcc
```

As the feature `x` is independent of the outcome `y`, the MCC winds up being rather low, around $-0.04$, not statistically significantly different from zero ($p \approx 0.2$ in `cor.test`).

Note that MCC suffers from [issues](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/603663/247274) similar to accuracy, sensitivity, specificity, precision, recall, $F_1$ score, and the $F_{\beta}$ score, and [this is true whether imbalance is present or not](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/247274).